Dropping question rate - Anything we can / should do about?
I sometimes monitor the Area 51 statistics for Crypto.SE.
I've noticed, that around the time where our graduation has been announced, that our questions / day ratio is radically dropping (9.2 IIRC -> 7.9 as of now) and I don't see this trend stopping.
Is there anything we should / can do about this?

although we have summer, the number of questions is rising now again. 9.4 as of now :)

The Area 51 statistics average over a recent period, IIRC 2 weeks. A 15% variation over such a short time span is not “radically dropping”, it's barely over statistical noise. You can see historical data on the Data Explorer. So far June 2015 looks on track to be only slightly behind May (3 more days left as the data is from the morning of the 28th), and data from previous years confirm e-sushi's claim of traffic dropping in the summer months (~150 q/months in 2014, against >200 the rest of the year).

It´s summer-time… a time where Crypto.SE usually sees less questions (and answers). Looking back at the past few years, the ratio should increase again around the time school/college/university starts, as students tend to drop by asking questions related to their new courses in cryptography and/or information security.

Is there anything we should / can do about this?

Sure. If you can come up with some good questions yourself, please feel invited to post them. Besides that, it never hurts to spread the word about Crypto.SE so people know it exists (as new members tend to ask new questions too). So, if you can´t come up with new questions yourself and you really want to do something for Crypto.SE, a bit of propaganda via social networks and/or your website (if you own one) might help fill part of the gap.
